# Is there a way to copy @id column generatedValue to another column of same entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a requirement in SpringBoot JPA service where the primary key value of the column must be stored in another column of same entity. In example below, `rowId` is generated by `StringPrefixedLineSequenceIdGenerator`. Whatever value it generates, I need to store the same in `lineId` column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CX_LINE")
public class CXLine {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cx_line_seq")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cx_line_seq", 
    strategy = "com.tmo.chub.entity.generator.StringPrefixedLineSequenceIdGenerator"/*, 
                parameters = {@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedLineSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "2-XP-"),
                              @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedLineSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%04d")}*/)
   @Column(name="row_id")
   private String rowId;

   @Column(name="LINE_ID")
   private String lineId;

   //getters & setters
}
```

The issue is, the value of `@id` will not be available to me until the `repo.save()`. Is there a way to get the generatedValue from hibernate session or something? or Is it possible to use `@GeneratedValue` & `@GenericGenerator` for columns other than `@id`? 
I am currently doing 2 saves. I will save the new CXline with unique value (coming in input) and then do the update again like shown below. Appreciate any inputs here.

```java
CXLine existingLine = lineRepo.findByExtLineId(payload.getCustomerProfile().getCustomerId());

if(existingLine !=null){
   //do update
}
else{
   CXLine newLine = new CXLine();   
   newLine.setLineId(payload.getCustomerProfile().getCustomerId());
   // set other columns
   lineRepo.save(newLine);

   CXLine lineToUpdateLineId = lineRepo.findByExtLineId(payload.getCustomerProfile().getCustomerId());
   lineToUpdateLineId.setLineId(lineToUpdateLineId.getRowId());
   lineRepo.save(newLine);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the same functionality in a different way.
If you don't want to save the same object two times
Then, first generating the sequence using @query annotation with a native SQL query on repository.

example

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cx_line_seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL", nativeQuery = true)
    public Long getCxLineId();
```

then setting the value to columns and saving them.
if you are using above approach then you need to remove the sequence generator from your Entity class

Comment: Thanks Shilanand. But I use SequenceStyleGenerator to to add a prefix to the sequence. Will i be able to do that if i remove the Sequence Generator?

Comment: Yes DHR, it is nothing but getting sequence separately and then setting it to the primary key (in your case setting it to rowId and lineId)