# Get generated ID in JPA in pre persist method before commit?

Tags: java, jpa

The entity has a  generic ID generator,

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "seq_id", strategy = "com.yoncabt.abys.core.listener.CustomGenerator", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "II_FIRM_DOC_PRM_SEQ") })
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String token;
    private string filepath;
    private String value;
    
     @PrePersist
    private void prePersistFunction(){

        log.info("PrePersist method called");
        filepath = id+".txt";
        write value to this file (filetpath)
        value = null;
    }

    ...
    //getters
    //equals and hashcode
}
```

The file path value gets id as null in this case.

How can I get the value of id in preperists since this is a custom genric generator not by database?

Thanks

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simon-martinelli can you please help.

Comment: `filepath` looks like a calculated column, why do you have to persist it if it can be easily computed with `id+".txt"`

Comment: the id string adds uniqueness to it, Which needs to be the same as the id field to be able to update.

Comment: IDs are generated during persistence. Your method is marked with **Pre**Persist. But guess what - you can use **Post**Persist ;) The only other way is to use assigned ID generation strategy - and set the IDs _manually_. Note though that this object isn't saved in DB until the transaction is committed, so not sure why you're trying to do this in PrePersist anyway. Also note - ORM will not even INSERT the new record if your ID generation strategy doesn't require it (which seems like your case).

Comment: And.. since what you're doing looks super weird - maybe you could add explanation of what you're trying to achieve and why. It's possible we'll come up with a better solution.

Comment: May be this is helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60715583/3493829

Comment: you need to do workaround as mentioned in this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa)

Answer (score 4):

You can not do that in pre persist. `@PrePersist` annotated function is executed before persist is called for a new entity. At this point **the Id has not been generated yet** so you can not compose a field based on it.

You could do that in your custom generator. Your custom generator should have a `generate` method where you calculate and return the entity Id. You also get access to the entity being persisted so in addition to that you can set the composed field:

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) {

    long id = // Calculate new id

    // obj is the entity being persisted whose identifier will be set with calculated id 
    // We can set other fields as well
    Customer customer = (Customer) obj;
    customer.setFilepath(id+".txt");

    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do work around to get the generated Id in sequence, this answer will help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa)